# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Topic name can only have ASCII alphanumerics, '.', '_' and '-', but was: ' consumer-in-0'

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka

In my application.yml, I have this code :

```
spring.cloud.stream:
  function:
    definition: producer; processor; consumer
  bindings:
    producer-out-0:
      destination: numbers
    processor-in-0:
      destination: numbers
    processor-out-0:
      destination: squares
    consumer-in-0:
      destination: squares
```

But I am getting this error: Topic name can only have ASCII alphanumerics, '.', '_' and '-', but was: ' consumer-in-0'.
Can someone see what is the issue?

Comment: Must be a misleading nested error, Add a line break after last `squares`?

Comment: No, That was the last-line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I founded the error in this line there should be no spaces after semi-colons:

```
definition: producer; processor; consumer
```

It should be like:

```
definition: producer;processor;consumer
```